# React native I do not understand the sentences

Tags: react-native

I just do not know how the code works below, mind if anyone can tell me how it's working this?? I do not understand especially "=>" what does this do?

```
React.Children.map(this.props.children, (child) => {};
```

Comment: What research so far have you done?

Answer (score 2):

This is an arrow expression. It creates a function. There's nothing in the curly braces, so no code will execute. It's part of JavaScript, not React Native-related.

For example, you could write a function named `myFunction` like this:

```
var myFunction = (name) => {
    console.log("Hello, " + name);
}
```

See the MDN docs for more info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions